# How to use global timer on Cortex A9 in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux

I write a program to read the global timer on on the cortex A9 of the OMAP4460 (Pandaboard ES).  From the OMAP4 TRM [section 4.4.1] and the Cortex-A9 MPCore TRM [section 1.5](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407g/CACCJFCJ.html) , I can tell that the base address for the ARM9 gloabal timer registers is 0x4824 0200. The Cortex-A9 MPCore TRM [section 4.4.1](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407g/CIHHEJDF.html) says "There are two timer counter registers. They are the lower 32-bit timer counter at offset 0x00 and the upper 32-bit timer counter at offset 0x04". So the codes I wrote is as following , but it abort with segment fault . I don't what's wrong ? Does anyone know how exactly to read global timer on cortex A9 in Linux?

```
#define GLOBAL_TIMER_BASE 0X48240200U

void  rdGlobalTimer()
{
  unsigned int _low,_high;
  unsigned int addr = GLOBAL_TIMER_BASE;
  __asm__ __volatile__("ldr %0, [%1]\n\t"\
        : "=&r"(_low)
            : "r" (addr)
        : "memory");

  __asm__ __volatile__("ldr %0, [%1]\n\t"\
        : "=&r"(_high)
            : "r" (addr + 4)
        : "memory");



   printf("low:%x,high:%x\n",_low,_high);
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing this?  In the `kernel` or `user space`?  Maybe don't tag **linux** to make it more obvious.  Everything uses the MMU in Linux, even the kernel.  You need to make sure the address is mapped.  Typically, it is registered as a resource and then a driver claims it.  Also, I understand it is an **arm** CPU, but the question is not related to **arm** generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map (`mmap`) that address space, and most obvious way of doing that is via `/dev/mem`.

Try to compile and use [devmem2.c](http://www.lartmaker.nl/lartware/port/devmem2.c) for your target, for example

```
devmem2 0X48240200
```

You should study the example but idea is just about

```
...
if((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) FATAL;
map_base = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, target & ~MAP_MASK);
if(map_base == (void *) -1) FATAL;
...
```